# Java8 - CompletableFuture - Running methods in async call sequentially

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future, forkjoinpool

So I have this code block:

```
 someMethod(SomeParameter someParameter) {
  for (SomeObject: object) {
    if (someObject is true) {
      callSomeMethod(someParameter);
    } else {
      callSomeMethodInstead(someParameter);
    }
  }
}

callSomeMethod(SomeParameter someParameter) {
  someObjectdataFromDb = getFromDB(someId);
  boolean checker = checkIfNull(someObjectdataFromDb ) || checkIfHasCertainStatus(someObjectdataFromDb );
  if (checker) {
    callAnExternalAPI(someParameter);
  }
}
```

Then it's being called asynchronously:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync{()->{someMethod(someParameter);}}
```

Now, the issue is that the team owning the external API is telling us that we're making multiple calls at them at the same time resulting to some issues on creating the data. Is there a way that I can make sure the code happening on *callSomeMethod* is happening sequentially?

Edit: read that ForkJoinPool has a work-stealing algo, might that be the cause of the issue?

Comment: The code you put in this question is already sequential, the fact that you run it through `runAsync()` does not change that. Are you triggering several calls to `someMethod()` in parallel and you just want to prevent parallel calls to `callSomeMethod()`? If yes, is `callSomeMethodInstead()` problematic too? Because if that’s the case there does not seem to be much benefit in executing `someMethod()` in parallel (except maybe for the `getFromDB()` call?). Also, they should fix their API…

Comment: This is the only call to that method. It shouldn't be triggered on any flow. Yeah that's what I've thought, they should fix it on their side.

Comment: If they complain, I suppose it really means you are making parallel calls, so they must come from somewhere. Maybe this `runAsync()` call is executed multiple times from different threads? E.g., for different HTTP requests coming in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

> read that ForkJoinPool has a work-stealing algo, might that be the
> cause of the issue?

Doubt it, any kind of thread pool would allow for multiple of this to be executed concurrently.

If you need to make sure it's only being invoked one-at-a-time, you could make `callSomeMethod` synchronized (assuming it's either static or on a singleton object).  Note that this means things block indefinitely, so make sure you have appropriate timeouts in the interaction with the external service.

If you have more sophisticated needs, for example can allow some limited concurrency (like up to 3 at a time is fine but no more or similar), or are looking for timeouts, I'd suggest using a [resilience4j bulkhead](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/bulkhead), I've used that for this purpose quite successfully.